# selecting data in big table for which certain IDs don't exist in same columns. Speed up query

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization

I'm trying to select data in a table for companies and dates that don't exist for a different type/id of data.

Put another way, I want `company_id, dates_id, daily_val` where `wh_calc_id = 344` if the same `company_id/dates_id` combination doesn't exist where `wh_calc_id = 368`.

I'm loosely following this example:
[Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table)

These are my two attempts at it:

attempt 1:

```
SELECT distinct on (company_id, dates_id) company_id, dates_id, daily_val
FROM   daily_data d1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
                       SELECT 1              
                       FROM   daily_data d2
                       WHERE  d1.company_id = d2.company_id
                              and d1.dates_id = d2.dates_id
                              and d1.wh_calc_id = 368
                              and d2.wh_calc_id = 368
                   )
    and d1.wh_calc_id = 344
```

The problem: 
It's super slow: 27 minutes

attempt 2: [removed]

All in one (giant) table:
company_id int (indexed),
dates_id int (indexed),
wh_calc_id int (indexed), 
daily_val numeric

I'm open to adding an index that would help speed things up, but what index?

Postgres 10

<s>PS - I've had to kill both queries before they completed, so I don't really know if they are written correctly. Hopefully my description helps.</s>

Comment: I would do it whit a left join this way: SELECT distinct on (company_id, dates_id) company_id, dates_id, daily_val FROM daily_data d1 LEFT JOIN daily_data d2 ON d1.company_id = d2.company_id and d1.dates_id = d2.dates_id and d1.wh_calc_id = 368 and d2.wh_calc_id = 368 WHERE d1.wh_calc_id = 344 AND d2.company_id IS NULL; and create the index over the columns to use: Create index on table daily_data ( company_id, dates_id, wh_calc_id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I want I think:

```
   SELECT 
    d1.* 
from 
    daily_data d1
LEFT JOIN
    daily_data d2
ON
    d1.company_id     = d2.company_id
    AND d1.dates_id   = d2.dates_id
    AND d2.wh_calc_id = 368
    AND d1.wh_calc_id = 344

where
   and  d1.wh_calc_id = 344
   and d2.wh_calc_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a left join this way:

`SELECT distinct on (company_id, dates_id) company_id, dates_id, daily_val FROM daily_data d1 LEFT JOIN daily_data d2 ON d1.company_id = d2.company_id and d1.dates_id = d2.dates_id and d1.wh_calc_id = 368 and d2.wh_calc_id = 368 WHERE d1.wh_calc_id = 344 AND d2.company_id IS NULL;`

and create the index over the columns to use:

`Create index on table daily_data ( company_id, dates_id, wh_calc_id);`

Comment: turns out that didn't do what I wanted.